# Remote Desktop - xfce4 works but gnome & ubuntu do not

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvncserver

**~/.vnc/xstartup**

*Using xfce4 works:*

```
if which startxfce4 > /dev/null; then
    exec startxfce4 
fi
```

[image]

*Using gnome / ubuntu does not work:*

```
if [ -r "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
        xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
# gnome-session --session=gnome &
# gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback &
```

[image: vnc blank screen X cursor]

**$ ls /usr/share/xsessions**

```
gnome-fallback-compiz.desktop  gnome.desktop   xfce.desktop
gnome-fallback.desktop         ubuntu.desktop
```

## Question

How can I get Ubuntu's default window manager to start in a VNC connection?